# Interactive rendering for a video in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

For each input from the user, I would like to render a different video based on a different **src**,
I have tested many methods non of them has served my needs, I am relying on extracting the src path from a specific cell in a CSV file

would you please assist me to figure out how to do that, the following line is the main part that is need to be adjusted to solve the problem:

tags$iframe(width="560", height="315", src=uiOutput('link1'))

```
 library(shiny)

 Targeted_sector<- c('Wastewater Treatment','Agriculture Schemes','Dams' )
 Targeted_year<- c('2021','2022','2023' )


 Wastewater_Treatment<- read.csv("data/Wastewater_Treatment.csv", header=TRUE, 
                               check.names=FALSE)
 Agriculture_Schemes<- read.csv("data/Agriculture_Schemes.csv", header=TRUE,  
                                 check.names=FALSE)
 Dams<- read.csv("data/Dams.csv", header=TRUE,  check.names=FALSE)


ui <- 
fluidPage(

    sidebarPanel(
  
       selectInput('sector',
              'Targeted Sector:',
              Targeted_sector),
       selectInput('year1',
              'Targeted Year:',
              Targeted_year)
 
        )
          )


    mainPanel(
     tags$iframe(width="560", height="315", src=uiOutput('link1'), frameborder="0", 
     allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture", 
     allowfullscreen=NA)

     # here I want src to change dynamically according to the input$sector 

         )



    server <- function(input, output) {



    SelectSector <-reactive({

    if (input$sector == 'Wastewater Treatment')
    {
     return(Wastewater_Treatment) 
    }
      else if (input$sector == 'Agriculture Schemes')
    {
      return(Agriculture_Schemes)
    } 

     else  
    {
     return(Dams)
    } 
                            })





 SelectYear  <- reactive({
 if (input$year1 %in%  SelectSector()$years)
 {
  SelectSector() %>%
    filter(years == input$year1) %>%
    pull(link) # This contain the targeted link for example"https://www.youtube.com/watchv=L7KSftmYce0" but it did not work 
  }
 
            })

  output$link1 <- 
  renderUI({
  tagList(SelectYear())
        })
        }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the video is on YouTube, you can just use their standard embedded Iframe. Only use the video ID, because you want to use a different URL (https://www.youtube.com/embed/ instead of https://www.youtube.com/watch). Create a character string with the selected ID and let shiny tell that it is HTML code instead of text to render the UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

videos <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B"),
  # youtube video ids (part of URL)
  id = c("LXb3EKWsInQ", "xcJtL7QggTI")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("name", "Name of Video to watch", c("A", "B")),
  uiOutput("video")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$video <- renderUI({
    id <- videos |>
      filter(name == input$name) |>
      pull(id) |>
      first()
    
    paste0(
      "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/",
      id,
      "' title='YouTube video player'",
      "frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write;",
      "encrypted-media;gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    ) |> HTML()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]